# easy ways to select data from more than 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i want to select some rows in my mysql databases, I have 3 tables with the different structure ( but each table has the same column, "command" ), I have tried using the script that I created and this works, but it seems like it takes too many lines in my script.

```
<?php
$check1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM text WHERE keyword='$string'");
$check2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sticker WHERE keyword='$string'");
$check3 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM image WHERE keyword='$string'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($check1) == 0 && mysqli_num_rows($check2) == 0 && mysqli_num_rows($check3) == 0) {
    echo "success";
}
?>
```

is there another way to shorten my script above ? thank you :)

Comment: The number of code lines are never a good indication of code quality. You probably need more lines to code this well. Apart from that: What does this code achieve? Why 'success' when `$string` doesn't exist as a `keyword` in any of your three tables?

Answer (score 0):

you should use  "join" query  to get all data from all different tables where "command" is same then where check1=0

Answer (score 0):

Use a mysql `JOIN` clause.
This will return all the data from 3 tables and you interact with the results as a single dataset.

`SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.keyword = table2.keyword JOIN table3 ON table3.keyword = table1.keyword;`

And in case there are similar columns in both tables, you will need to alias them as you return them from the query to prevent conflicts.

`SELECT table1.column, table2.column FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.keyword = table2.keyword JOIN table3 ON table3.keyword = table1.keyword;`